# Issue when using Ticks and Frame

Tags: plotting

```
ParametricPlot[{θ*180/π, Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0,π},    
  Ticks -> {{0, 45, 90, 135, 180}, Automatic}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {90, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 1200, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

When I use `Ticks` and `Frame` together, the `Ticks` do not appear at the positions specified:

```
ParametricPlot[{θ*180/π, Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π},  
  Ticks -> {{0, 45, 90, 135, 180}, Automatic}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {90, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 1200, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Of course, they don't. `Ticks` only applies to axes, not frames. You want to use `FrameTicks`, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FrameTicks` when using frames.

```
ParametricPlot[{θ*180/π, Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π},
  FrameTicks -> {{0, 45, 90, 135, 180}, Automatic}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {90, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 600, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 25],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> True]
```